# JAVAFX listview blank row selection issue

Tags: java, listview, javafx, netbeans, fxml

In JavaFX ListView when an item is selected it works properly but as soon as the user clicks on any blank row in the list view it shows the previous object that was selected.I made no use of ObservableList as it was of no use here(as per my thought).

```
 @FXML
private void performSearch(ActionEvent event) 
{
    ListView.getItems().clear();
    String srch = SearchBar.getText();

    Connection c = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    try
    {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase","AK","123");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Student where NAME like"+"'"+srch+"%'");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String a = rs.getString("NAME");
            ListView.getItems().add(a);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){} 


}


@FXML
private void displaySelected(MouseEvent event) throws IOException 
{

     String nm;          
    nm = ListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    //here nm always retains the old selected String
     System.out.println("Selected : "+nm);
    pass=nm;

    Parent hm_pg_prnt = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StudSearchDisplay.fxml"));
    Scene hm_pg_scene = new Scene(hm_pg_prnt);
    Stage app_stage = new Stage();//(Stage)( (Node) event.getSource() ).getScene().getWindow();
      app_stage.hide();
    app_stage.setScene(hm_pg_scene);
    app_stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    app_stage.show();
```

}

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly. And  please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. And ... please read a decent tutorial (see the info page of the javafx tag) instead of assuming what's needed or not ;)

Comment: Thanks sir @kleopatra , I will keep that in  mind. :)

Comment: Is your `ListView` seriously named "ListView?" Also, definitely use an `ObservableList` and get in the habit of doing so; it will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Yup, that's I mistake, Thanks :)